# Prevent visual studio from building when i Debug-> Start New Instance

Tags: c#, .net, debugging, visual-studio-2013

I am working on a very large solution which can take 10 minutes or more to build. 
Most of the time if I right click on my project and select "Debug" -> "Start New Instance" Visual Studio decides it wants to build everything again.

Is there a way to ask Visual Studio to launch and debug the current build regardless of whether code files have changed?

I know I can launch my executable manually and then attach but that's time consuming and I need to step into my code from the beginning.

Answer (score 4):

You can find the settings for this under "Tools" > "Options" > "Projects and Solutions" > "Build and Run"

Although setting them correctly seems to be tricky =) [See here](https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/vstudio/en-US/8657c07a-da08-4a9f-9558-0c9d93c94ce2/start-debugging-f5-doesnt-automatically-build?forum=vsdebug)